# Directory structure for angular

Tags: angular

I have seen the directory structure on angular.io but I am not satisfied with the guidelines they have provided. Typically we have services and models which can be used in any module, please take a look at the following structure

```
app
 |---modules
 |         |---account
 |         |         |---list-account.component.ts|html|css
 |         |         |---add-account.component.ts|html|css
 |         |---customer
 |                   |---list-customer.component.ts|html|css
 |                   |---add-customer.component.ts|html|css 
 |---services
 |          |---account.service.ts
 |          |---customer.service.ts
 |---models
 |        |---account.model.ts
 |        |---customer.model.ts
```

I have tried to use  the following structure but while importing the files in typescript the relative urls are too unclear. for example If I want to import `account.model` in `add-account.component`, the import statement looks like this

```
// ../../ looks so wierd, is it a good practise?
import { AccountModel } from  '../../models/account.model';

// is it good practise to use absolute paths to import for typescript in angular?
import { AccountModel } from '~/models/account.model';
```

I want to re-use my models in all the components and services has to be re-used. Please suggest me some good directory structure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use **barrels** for imports. Absolute path reference is always good when you are moving to production it reduces the effort compared to relative paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular Style Guide designed by [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), shows to use the partial way is encouraged. So you should use:

```js
import { AccountModel } from  '../../models/account.model';
```

Source: [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#import-line-spacing)